# Evernote FindNote closure issue in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using evernote and want to download all the note in my samdbox. 
as per documentation to find the note the code is given as in objective c

```
[[ENSession sharedSession] findNotesWithSearch:[ENNoteSearch noteSearchWithSearchString:@"redwood"]
                                        inNotebook:nil
                                           orScope:ENSessionSearchScopeDefault
                                         sortOrder:ENSessionSortOrderRecentlyCreated
                                        maxResults:20
                                        completion:^(NSArray * findNotesResults, NSError * findNotesError) {
        if (findNotesResults) {
            for (ENSessionFindNotesResult * result in findNotesResults) {
                // Each ENSessionFindNotesResult has a noteRef along with other important metadata.
                NSLog(@"Found note with title: %@", result.title);
            }
        }
    }];
```

But I write my project in swift and call the same method but I find dificulty to replace the objective c block to swift closure. and it give me error [image: See Picture for Error.]

```
 ENSession.sharedSession().findNotesWithSearch(nil, inNotebook: nil, orScope: .Personal, sortOrder: .RecentlyUpdated, maxResults: 100, completion: {(results:NSArray!, error:NSError) in



                });
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time spending on the problem I have found an answer

```
ENSession.sharedSession().findNotesWithSearch(nil, inNotebook: nil, orScope: .None, sortOrder: .RecentlyUpdated, maxResults: 100, completion: {(results:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError?) in

                self.noteList = results

            });
```